# Umbraco - Passing data from surface controller to view

Tags: umbraco

I'm creating this contact form which is pretty much what you can find on the documentation:
http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Mvc/forms

The problem is that on my action I'm adding some data to the ViewData collection but I'm unable to get in on the view.

Here is the action:

```
public ActionResult ProcessForm(ContactFormModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        // do something here
        return CurrentUmbracoPage();
    }    
    // process form
    // set success flag
    ViewData("SuccessMessage") = "We will be contacting you soon..";
    return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
}
```

Here is the view:

```
<h1>@ViewData("SuccessMessage")</h1>
```

It will return this error:

> Compilation Error, Error Message: CS0103: The name 'ViewData' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewData should be set and called using `ViewData["some key"]`, not `ViewData("some key")`. This is because ViewData is essentially a dictionary and not a method on the `ControllerBase` class.

See here for [a good explanation of its use](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/06/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-3-passing-viewdata-from-controllers-to-views.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot, while switching back and forth from vb.net to c# I endup missing that.

Answer (score 0):

This will  not work since you are redirecting another view/action, and that will not access to this ViewData.

If you want to do this, render a partial view.

Comment: In this case it does work since the Umbraco core re adds any object held in the ViewData.